# how to use LDAP in PHP Bluemix app?

Tags: php, ldap, ibm-cloud

I want to use LDAP in my bluemix app but I don't know how to install this extension. I tried adding a composer.json file with the next settings:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "ext-ldap": "*"
    }
}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LDAP extension is an extension to PHP and needs to be installed within the PHP runtime. Have a look at the extensions-section of the php-manual at php.net

When you use ext-ldap within the require section in your composer.json file composer will only run when the ldap-extension is available within the PHP runtime. It will **not** install the LDAP extension!